# Ignore scheduled date in agenda if item is "CANCELLED"?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Imaginee I set a deadline for Project A and the schedule date for task A1 and A2, now the project is cancelled (with CANCELLED todo keyword), which makes the scheduled date for A1 and A2 invalidated.

Note, I didn't remove the SCHEDULED: keywords in the sequential nodes. These information is useful if the project is activated again somehow.

I wonder what's the best way to ignore these dates (deadline and schedule) in the `org-agenda`?

The org buffer looks like this:

```
* CANCELLED Project A 
  DEADLINE: <2015-12-22 Tue>
** A1 
   SCHEDULED: <2015-12-25 Fri>
** A2 
   SCHEDULED: <2016-01-03 Sun>
```

This is the `org-agenda` buffer I have.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Children don't inherit the "done" state of their parents.  They do inherit *tags*, so you can set a special tag on the parent and tell the agenda to ignore anything with that tag.  In fact, org-mode provides such a tag out of the box: `ARCHIVE`.  You can (un)set it with `org-toggle-archive-tag` (`C-c C-x a`); see the [internal archiving](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-archiving.html#Internal-archiving) section of the manual.  Reviving the project is as simple as removing the archive tag (using `C-c C-x a` a second time).

If you want all `CANCELLED` projects to automatically be archived, you can have the tag automatically applied when the todo state changes:

```
(setq org-todo-state-tags-triggers
  '(("CANCELLED" ("ARCHIVE" . t))))
```

Comment: that's an excellent solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variables `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` and `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done` to `t` if you want your "done" [TODO items](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Items.html) to get skipped in the agenda.

Here's a link to the `org` manual node on [deadlines and scheduling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html) for more information..

So, for example:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t
      org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done  t
      org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "|" "DONE" "CANCELLED")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The tricky bit here is I didn't remove the SCHEDULED: keywords in the sequential nodes. These information is useful if the project is activated again somehow.

Comment: @yi.tang.uni: that was a reading comprehension fail on my part, sorry.

Comment: This did not work for me..

Answer (score 0):

you can also put COMMENT keyword first so subtasks will not be scanned for Scheduled tag.

i refile all DONE tasks to "COMMENT Done" and these DONE Task are not shown in Agenda

- COMMENT Done
- ** DONE asdfg

Good point is that you can have bird eye view about which projects are commented, you dont have to look for ARCHIVE Tagged projects

Sorry for such a poorly formatted answer